# How to count number of asked questions?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have this activity with question and 4 possible answers, and after each user answer it reloads itself with another question. I placed a textView in the bottom right corner with start value of `1/10` (`rezultat.setText(counter+"/10");`). I want to increase that value to 2/10, 3/10 and so on, after each question, but I don't know where to put counter++; in my code, and I tried everywhere. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Kviz extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
     };
     Runnable mLaunchTaskFinish = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            finish();
         }
      };

    Button bIzlazIzKviza, bOdgovor1, bOdgovor2, bOdgovor3, bOdgovor4;
    TextView question, proba, rezultat;
    int counter = 1;

    private class Answer {
        public Answer(String opt, boolean correct) {
            option = opt;
            isCorrect = correct;
        }

        String option;
        boolean isCorrect;
    }
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
            if (ans.isCorrect) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish, 1200);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1000);
                Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TACANODGOVOR");
                startActivity(i);

            }else{
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish, 2200);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2000);
                Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.POGRESANODGOVOR");
                startActivity(i);
                }
            }
     };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.kviz);

        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        Typeface pitanje = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");
        bIzlazIzKviza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzlazIzKviza);
        rezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrojPitanja);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanje);
        bOdgovor1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovor1);
        bOdgovor2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovor2);
        bOdgovor3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovor3);
        bOdgovor4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovor4);
        bOdgovor1.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor2.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor3.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor4.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bIzlazIzKviza.setTypeface(dugmad);
        rezultat.setTypeface(dugmad);
        question.setTypeface(pitanje);

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();


        try{    //Pokusava da otvori db
        mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

        Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData();

        question.setText(c.getString(1));

        List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
        labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

        Collections.shuffle(labels);

        bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
        bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
        bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
        bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
        bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
        bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
        bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
        bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
        bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        rezultat.setText(counter+"/10");
        }

        finally{    // kada zavrsi sa koriscenjem baze podataka, zatvara db
            mDbHelper.close();
        }

        bIzlazIzKviza.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();   
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the mean of "each user answer it reloads itself with another question." ? Are you using different Activities for diff question ?
You can use same activity for all the questions, when user press any of answer's button, just call a method

```
public void nextQuestion() {
    counter++;
    question.setText("");
    bOdgovor1.setText("");
    bOdgovor2.setText("");
    bOdgovor3.setText("");
    bOdgovor4.setText("");
    //reset your next question and all four options here
    rezultat.setText(counter + "/10");
}
```

Comment: did you check anything that i suggested..?

Comment: No, i'm using one activity for all questions, i just use startActivity(getIntent()); after each click to realod the activity with another question and seto of answers. And for your code...i don't write question directly in the code, i import them from prepopulated sqlite database.

Comment: if you will call startActivity(Intent) again and again for each question, the system will create multiple instances for this activity. and if you will destroy the previous instance before calling startActivity, then user will feel some screen flickering, that will affect user experience.

Comment: so read the questions and corresponding answers in once, and after every question get answered, call nextQuestion() and in this update question and options.

Comment: Actually, no. I did test it, and there is no flickering at all.

Comment: You're right, umesh. Your way is much better, with nextQuestion(). I did it like you said, and now my problem is solved, and my counter works. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Only thing I did quite get is where you say "//reset your next question and all four options here". I didn't do that and it still works fine. Can you explain that with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test from here, but it looks like adding `counter++` before the line

```
Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
```

Should work fine, as this sets `counter` to increment whenever the button that seems to be responsible for answering questions is clicked. Remember that you'll also need to call

```
rezultat.setText(counter+"/10");
```

Again, to update the text to reflect the new value of `counter`.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, i've just tried it. And what do you mean i have to call this other line? I am calling it, right bellow my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

To expand my problem a little bit. I did manage to count questions with counter class, it goes to 2/10, but because I reload my activity after each question, my textView also reloads to 1/10. I think that's the main cause of my problem.